# Asp.net login and session

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class Admin_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
        SqlConnection con = null;
       ConectionStrings cs = new ConectionStrings();
       SqlCommand comm = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
     SqlDataAdapter da;
    protected void btnadmin_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            con = new SqlConnection(cs.Db);
            con.Open();
            //string logincheck = "select * from Admin_login where admin_name =@username and admin_pwd=@password";
          string login = " Select * from Admin_login where admin_name = '" + txtadmin_name.Text + "' and admin_pwd = '" + txtadmin_pwd.Text + "' ";

            comm=new SqlCommand(login,con);
    //    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtadmin_name.Text);
    //        //  da = new SqlDataAdapter(login, con);
    //    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin_pwd", txtadmin_pwd.Text.Trim());
    //
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
           if (reader.Read())
            {


                Response.Redirect("Admin Add_Books.aspx");

           }
           else
           {
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
           }

            con.Close();









    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Admin_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
        SqlConnection con = null;
       ConectionStrings cs = new ConectionStrings();
       SqlCommand comm = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
     SqlDataAdapter da;
    protected void btnadmin_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            con = new SqlConnection(cs.Db);
            con.Open();
            //string logincheck = "select * from Admin_login where admin_name =@username and admin_pwd=@password";
          string login = " Select * from Admin_login where admin_name = '" + txtadmin_name.Text + "' and admin_pwd = '" + txtadmin_pwd.Text + "' ";

            comm=new SqlCommand(login,con);
    //    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtadmin_name.Text);
    //        //  da = new SqlDataAdapter(login, con);
    //    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin_pwd", txtadmin_pwd.Text.Trim());
    //
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
           if (reader.Read())
            {


                Response.Redirect("Admin Add_Books.aspx");

           }
           else
           {
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
           }

            con.Close();









    }
}
```

Everything is alright but when log-out and url same copy my home page same and back to the before page

Comment: please be more clear, what is the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: Please explain `url same copy my home page same` ? (-1) - for being not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is my admin login panel

```
public partial class Admin_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    SqlConnection con = null;
   ConectionStrings cs = new ConectionStrings();
   SqlCommand comm = null;
   SqlDataReader reader = null;
 SqlDataAdapter da;
  protected void btnadmin_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {


        con = new SqlConnection(cs.Db);
        con.Open();
        //string logincheck = "select * from Admin_login where admin_name =@username and admin_pwd=@password";
      string login = " Select * from Admin_login where admin_name = '" + txtadmin_name.Text + "' and admin_pwd = '" + txtadmin_pwd.Text + "' ";

        comm=new SqlCommand(login,con);
//    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtadmin_name.Text);
//        //  da = new SqlDataAdapter(login, con);
//    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin_pwd", txtadmin_pwd.Text.Trim());
//
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
       if (reader.Read())
        {


            Response.Redirect("Admin Add_Books.aspx");

       }
       else
       {
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
       }

        con.Close();
  }
 }
```

when i click login button when open my other page and when i log-out my page
then its back again login panel ..... everything is alright But One Probelm when i click backpage its return my internal page without log in Or when i coppy url my internal page and after log-out again i put my url in browser when this page show without login

But i have no password save browser

this page code here

```
        public partial class Admin_Add_Books : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        ConectionStrings cs = new ConectionStrings();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs.Db);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Library order by mem_id", con);
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(tb);
        tb.AcceptChanges();
        GridView_all_records.DataSource = tb;
        GridView_all_records.DataBind();
        con.Close();
}

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Admin Login.aspx");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to first understand the concept properly.
One is that you have used SQLDataAdapter and also opened and closed the connection. No you dont need to because SQLDataAdapter is use for closed Connection. Search for Open and Close connection in Asp.net On Google and read on microsoft official Site.

Second, Comming to your point, I just cannot see that you have used session anywhere. Upon successful login you should save some data in Session and on each page load check that session is not empty. So if it is then redirect again to login page and this way unautorized users cannot see your page. Check below example.

```
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Session["AdminLoginDetails"] = "logged In";   //Should actually be login details(datatable)
        Response.Redirect("Admin Add_Books.aspx");
   }
```

Now on each page's load event (that should not be visible without login)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (Session["AdminLoginDetails"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
    }
   }
```

Hope it helps.
And Also you should edit your question and not to add answer as a question. Use Edit button Below your Question to edit and make your question understandable. Your question was simple but your way of questioning made it difficult.